# ERD for property development

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have tried to create an ERD for the scenario below, and that's where I have got... But I have a feeling that I might miss something, or is it ok?
By the way the data needs to be normalized 3NF.

Scenario
Samuels Property Development are an architecture company based in Manchester, England. The company want you to design and implement a database that meets the requirements of their business. These requirements are specified in this scenario and the examples of paper documents kept by the company shown below.
Samuels Property Development specialise in managing high-value projects on behalf of the clients. Clients may have many projects but each project is assigned to a specific client. Projects are classified by type. Each project may have one or more staff assigned to it, but an individual member of staff can only work on one project at a particular time. Projects are made from materials such as bricks, timber and glass. There may be many materials in a project. Materials are obtained from a designated supplier.

[image]

And here is my SQL query so far:

```
-- STEP 1: Create lowry_property database
CREATE DATABASE lowry_property
GO
USE lowry_property;

-- STEP 2: Create ProjectType table
GO
CREATE TABLE ProjectType
(
    ProjectTypeID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ProjectTypeName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ProjectAddress nvarchar(255)
);

-- STEP 3: Create Supplier table
GO
CREATE TABLE Supplier
(
    SupplierID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    SupplierName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SupplierCity nvarchar(50),
    SupplierAddress nvarchar(255)
);

-- STEP 4: Create Material table
GO
CREATE TABLE Material
(
    MaterialID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    MaterialName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SupplierID int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Supplier (SupplierID)
);

-- STEP 5: Create StaffType table
GO
CREATE TABLE StaffType
(
    StaffTypeID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    StaffTypeName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);


-- STEP 7: Create Staff table
GO
CREATE TABLE Staff
(
    StaffID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    StaffFirstName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    StaffLastName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    StaffTypID int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES StaffType (StaffTypeID)
);

-- STEP 8: Create Project table

CREATE TABLE Project
(
    ProjectID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ProjectName nvarchar(255),
    ProjectTypeID int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProjectType (ProjectTypeID),
    ProjectStartDate date,
    ProjectEndDate date,
    StaffID int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Staff (StaffID),
    MaterialID int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Material (MaterialID)
);

-- STEP 9: Create County table
GO
CREATE TABLE County 
(
    CountyID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CountyName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

-- STEP 10: Create City table
GO
CREATE TABLE City 
(
    CityID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    City nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);

-- STEP 11: Create Address table
GO
CREATE TABLE Address 
(
    AddressID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Street nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PostCode nvarchar(15) NOT NULL,
);

-- STEP 12: Create Client table
GO
CREATE TABLE Client
(
    ClientID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ClientFirstName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ClientLastName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ClientAddress nvarchar(255),
    CountyID int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES County (CountyID),
    CityID int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES City (CityID),
    AddressID int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Address (AddressID),
    ProjectID int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Project (ProjectID)
);
```

Comment: School work or similar?

Comment: I'm doing some private study from home, and that's one of the examples which I ran into. Tried to solve it, although I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.